# Convert Time to a string format VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to format a date to a specific string and the code is returning incorect outcome.

`CDate(RDate).ToString("ddMMy")`

is returning the year as 2 digits is there a way to make it return the correct just last digit ? I know that I could substring to get the result but I would like to use a format string to allow customer to create their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just glue them together with String.Format():

```
    Dim dt = CDate(RDate)
    Dim s = String.Format("{0}{1}", dt.ToString("ddMM"), dt.Year Mod 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'y' just indicates that the leading 0 is to be removed if the year is between 0 and 9. There is no format for just getting the last digit of the year.

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for the available custom formats.

Answer (score 1):

The Custom Format year formats are limited to returning a  minimum of a 2 digit year except in the situation that Compentent_tech mentions where you are using y and the year is ending with a 00 to 09. you can check out the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4). You will need to use string manipulation to achieve what you want.

---

Using that fact you can try something like this.

```
Dim RDate As Date = Now.Date
Dim NDate As Date = New Date((RDate.Year Mod 10), RDate.Month, RDate.Day)
CDate(NDate).ToString("ddMMy")
```

Comment: That is almost correct: the special case of years 0 through 9 are handled with the y format string, which allows a single digit.

Comment: @competent_tech You are correct I edited it. It will work for just 1/10 of the Century though.

Comment: thank you both, I did see the formating from MS but I thought may be I missed something, obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now

CDate(dt).ToString("ddMMyy").Remove(4, 1)
```

this code removes first of 2 digit year value.